# How to permanently disable "Expand to current folder" feature?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, file-organization

I usually use the Navigation pane to move files to their folders..
I don't like that "Expand to current folder" change the look and position of my fav folders that i need.
So I disable this feature. Unfortunately, its keep going even when it's disabled! I note that this occurs when browsing an external hard drive folders and uses Crtl+Enter to open some directory ("open in a new window") that's will unfortunately forces the Navigation pane to "Expand to open (current) folder".

Is there a solution to permanently disable this annoying feature?

Here a [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B699e.png) of Ctrl+Enter of a folder shortcut located **at external drives**, which forces the "Expand to current folder" feature.

Here is a [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK1p9.png) of Ctrl+Enter of a folder shortcut located **at system-drive**, which not-forces the "Expand to current folder" feature.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK1p9.png) Where it keeps not-expanded nice and tidy like how i wish to have WHITHIN the external drives folders opened with new window/Path bar navigation, or shortcut file.

Notes:

- "Expand to open folder" & "Expand to current folder" is already disabled from the folder option,& from navigation pane's right-click.
- This issue occurs within External drive directories, the issue Not occurs with the system-installed drive folders and shortcuts.
- I use StartAllBack v3.5.4, but it's not effects the issue

Thanks, bm3

Update: I created a feedback [here](https://aka.ms/AAj0c55), I hop everybody can upvote on it

Answer (score 1):

You may disable this option in Explorer by right-click in an empty area
inside the navigation pane, and click on "Expand to open folder"
to toggle it Off if checked (unchecked is the default)

You may also disable "Expand to current folder" in Explorer :

- Open Folder Options
- Position to the View tab
- Uncheck "Expand to current folder"
- Click OK.

[image]

Another method to disable is by running the following `.bat` file :

```
@echo off

REG Add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /V NavPaneExpandToCurrentFolder /T REG_DWORD /D 00000000 /F

taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
```

Source : [Turn On or Off Expand to Current Folder in Navigation Pane of File Explorer in Windows 11](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/turn-on-or-off-expand-to-current-folder-in-navigation-pane-of-file-explorer-in-windows-11.2544/).

Comment: I tried this, and the .bat, It's still going. i updated the issue and added more important screenshot.

Comment: Try to set "Expand to open folder", close explorer as done in the `.bat` file (or logout and login), unset it, and restart Explorer again.

Comment: I tried, you mean to toggle it back and forth, i tried that also. but let me ask you, Didn't you faces my same issue with your machine? see i updated the post.

Comment: All my options under "Navigation pane" are turned off and I never saw this problem. But I'm on Windows 10, which might not have this problem.

Comment: The folder you show is one you appear to have opened. I have Windows 11 Pro (and have had for about 16 months) , I have the option shown and nothing shows up so I am at a loss as to what is annoying you.

Comment: I think you may possibly have Windows 11 22H2.  That has a new Home screen built in and replaces Quick Access.  Is this the case?

Comment: Right i have Windows 11 22H2. the annoying is that even the option is unchecked, it still not disabled in action, it still going like if it is checked, did you face same thing? note that it's going and occurs in External Drive folders. while in system drive no problem.

Comment: If the option is malfunctioning, you need to signal it via the Feedback Hub and wait for a fix. This seems like a bug that only Microsoft can fix.

Comment: That's right, in this case it seems to be a bug, i realize that when updating the post later while trying to recognize when it happens and when not happening, then trying to describe the problem precisely. so it's a bug because it's malfunction with some cases and function with other all that in same pc. just can we check if i am not alone faces this bug? so it's not just me faces this problem? can you kindly check with yours, pay attention using external hard drive.

Comment: I created a feedback using MS feedback hub here you can check it: https://aka.ms/AAistl5

Comment: Attempting to look at your feedback only gives the message "Your account doesn't have access to this feedback."

Comment: My MS account belong to an organization, maybe that's the reason. the Feedback actually is copy of this post. i will update here when MS respond

Comment: There is nothing new in the MS feedback (today 06.12.2022)

Comment: There is nothing new in the MS feedback (today 15.12.2022)

Comment: I have created another feedback from another account so you can vote on it. https://aka.ms/AAj0c55

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue for external drives and the workaround I just found was through [this tutorial](https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/how_to_stop_file_explorer_from_showing_external_drives_twice.html) where you delete the registry for showing external hard drives as a separate option to the This PC listing of them, so now I just have This PC always expanded and whenever I navigate through the hard drives, it doesn't keep opening them up.

Makes the whole navigation pane a lot cleaner too!

Comment: For me not worked, maybe i ruined the registry already by trying a lot of things, thank you anyway.